# How to filter a list of records on clietndside based om checkbox criteria

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, javascript, dynamic, criteria-filter

I have tried using filters in a lightning component which filters records based on criteria. How can I toggle the filter based on true or false of a checkbox.

The issue I have currently is when ik toggle the checkbox back I do not get my old results and cant combine this dynamically with more filters. See my code below.

Checkbox

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Workshop" onchange="{!c.Workshop}"/>
```

Filter

```
 Workshop : function(component, event) {
    var itemList = component.get("v.opleidingen");
    var newList = [];
    for (var item of itemList){
     if(item.Opleidingstype__c  === 'Workshop'){
    newList.push(item);
    }
    component.set('v.opleidingen',newList);    
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are completely overwriting the original list.  To avoid this, you can save the full list to another attribute on the component and display a filtered version.  You are also not actually checking the value of the checkbox, so your condition is always being applied.

Your component might look more like this:

```
<lightning:attribute name="originalList" type="Object[]" /> /*Populate this with the full list*/ 
<lightning:attribute name="isWorkshop" type="Boolean" />

<lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Workshop" onchange="{!c.Workshop}" checked="{!v.isWorkshop}"/>
```

And your controller:

```
Workshop : function(component, event) {
var isWorkshopFilter = component.get("v.isWorkshop");
var fullList = component.get("v.originalList");
var filteredList = [];
for (var item of itemList){
 if(isWorkshopFilter && item.Opleidingstype__c  === 'Workshop'){
newList.push(item);
}
component.set('v.opleidingen',filteredList);    
}}
```

Note that we added the binding of the "checked" attribute on the checkbox to a new attribute, and then used that in the if condition of the loop.

Comment: I tried the following:   doInit : function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.findAll");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
             component.set("v.originalList", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }                             <aura:attribute name="originalList" type="Opleiding__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="isWorkshop" type="Boolean" />          Error:Failing descriptor: {c:OpleidingenList}

Comment: Did you add the new attributes to the controller file?  They should be added to the component markup file.

Comment: Yes to the component markup. The only difference is the aura part: <aura:attribute name="originalList" type="Opleiding__c[]" /> <aura:attribute name="isWorkshop" type="Boolean" />